# how load block in controller

Tags: blocks, controllers

I use the following code to load a block in controller

```
$this->loadLayout();
      if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart1')) {
        $cartlink =  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart1')->toHtml();
      }
```

1. Here the **checkout.cart1** is block name.
2. My layout file code is

   > ```
   > <quickbuy_index_index>  
   > <reference name="content">
   > <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart1">
   > <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart1.phtml</value></action>
   > <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
   >           .
   >           .
   >           .
   > </block>
   > </reference>
   > </quickbuy_index_index>
   > ```
3. Here my tag is `<quickbuy_index_index>`
4. Now the controller code not load my block .
5. But When i put the layout code within `<default>` tag instead of `<quickbuy_index_index>` tag, the controller load the block. like this

> ```
> <default>
> <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart1">
> <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart1.phtml</value></action>
> <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
>           .
>           .
>           .
> </block>
> </default>
> ```
>
> 6.  How i load the block in controller from `<quickbuy_index_index>` tag.

7. My problem is, When i put a block in **`<default>`** tag, the controller load it.
   when i put a same block in **url tag (`<quickbuy_index_index>`)** the controller not load it.

Comment: are you using ajax to load this block?

Comment: yes i  using ajax to load this block

Answer (score 3):

To load a block in `controller` file:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart')->setTemplate('checkout/cart1.phtml');
$html = $block->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simple render layout in your controller action as below

```
public function indexAction()
    {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();  
    }
```